# async update listbox in task.run

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous

I'm making a program which checks a dataset for problems with the data, and if it finds something, it needs to write the problem to a listbox.
As it is a very long process, I'm using async and await keywords so the user can keep using other Windows.

In the button handler, I wrote the following code:

```
Private Async Sub BtnIniciar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnIniciar.Click
 (...)
Await ValidaFracoesRepetidas()
 (...)
End Sub
```

In the sub, I'm trying to do the following:

```
Private Async Function ValidaFracoesRepetidas() As Task
        Await Task.Run(Sub()
         (...)
         ListProblems.Items.Add("the building " & edf.EdificioId & " has repeated rooms " &    frac(i) & " in floor " & patual)
         (...)
         End Sub)
End Function
```

But once it reaches the ListProblems.Items.Add the program throws an exception.
I want to know if is there a way to write to the listbox in the UI from another thread. If not can I return a Task(Of List(Of String)) and then in the ui thread write the values to the ListBox with a For Each?

Note: ListProblems is the name of a listbox in the ui (windows forms), if you need that I show more code, please ask and I'll give you more.

Thanks a lot for your attention and sorry, because I'm a very beginner in multithreading,

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (I'm a C# dev):

```
Private Async Function ValidaFracoesRepetidas() As Task
    Await Task.Run(Sub()
      (...)
      End Sub)
    ListProblems.Items.Add(...)
    Await Task.Run(Sub()
      (...)
      End Sub)
End Function
```